# Mysql - insert values from related table on insert?

Tags: mysql, triggers

This statement works:

```
UPDATE 
    registrations 
    JOIN players ON registrations.aa_player_id = players.a_player_id 
SET 
    registrations.`Player First`=players.player_first,    
    registrations.`Player Last`=players.player_last,    
    registrations.`Player Gender`=players.gender,
    players.date_of_birth=registrations.player_dob ;
```

I would like to set up a trigger to do the same thing (for just the one row) whenever a new row is added to the table *registrations*

I have tried this code

CREATE TRIGGER `lookup_player`
   BEFORE INSERT ON `registrations`
   FOR EACH ROW 
   update registrations

set
    new.`Player Last`=players.player_last,
    new.`Player First`=players.player_first,
     new.registrations.`Player Gender`=players.gender,
    new.player_dob=players.date_of_birth
  where new.aa_player_id=players.a_player_id;

But I get an error when I add a new row to *registrations*

*1054 - Unknown column 'players.a_player_id' in 'where clause'*

But that column *does* exist

Comment: In this case, pls show us what you have tried and what error message or unexpected behaviour you experienced.

Comment: "Can't seem to get it to work?"...why, what did you try exactly? What goes wrong? We can't fix a problem with code we can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
CREATE  TRIGGER `lookup player`
```

BEFORE INSERT ON `registrations` 
   FOR EACH ROW
   set
   new.`Player Last`=(select players.player_last from players where new.aa_player_id=players.a_player_id),
   new.`Player First`=  (select  players.player_first  from players where new.aa_player_id=players.a_player_id),
   new.`Player Gender`=  (select  players.gender  from players where new.aa_player_id=players.a_player_id),
   new.player_dob=    (select players.date_of_birth from players where new.aa_player_id=players.a_player_id);